# how to enable caching static resources in Jboss AS 7?

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow

So, our application in PROD server is taking extra time just navigating from one menu to another. As I investigate I see that my all static resources (CSS, scripts, images) are not caching and whenever user refresh the page it is not getting it from the cache. And the reason I believe this is happening is I see some 1969 year as expiry value in browser cache TAB(Attached image). I tried all the old solution I can find in here but none of them are working for me. I am using Spring web flow, Primefaces 6.1, JBoss as 7.1.1 server, JSF Mojarra 2.2.4.

I tried configuring context param in web.xml but did not work:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
    <param-value>604800</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES</param-name>
    <param-value>2592000000</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>-1</param-value>
</context-param> -->
```

i tried to configure in JBoss's standalone.xml for caching static resources but i did not find any good instructions.

so all i want to do is cahce all those static resources including files coming from Primefaces library let say 1 day expiry period. i strongly beleive the expiry value in Cache TAB is 1969 which is past and thus forcing browser to request all those files again instead of storing them in cache and retreiving it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Same application in jboss server 4.2 version request/response headers:
[image]

Comment: i am not sure but it may depend on browser, check your browser setting, or time picked up by browser and server.

Comment: And read about http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/CacheControlFilter

Comment: well, i read that link, it talks about omnifaces not primefaces and all i want to know is how to configure Cache Expires date which is showing 1969 now because of default Jboos as 7 server request header behavior. I just can not figure it out how to override this expires value either in Standalone.xml or application web.xml. i just know that if i can override this value to be like 24 hours instead of 1969, my static resources will be cached and my problem will go away.

Comment: Please learn about the differences between PrimeFaces and Omnifaces and what their 'use-case' is. Your first remark is sort of 'wrong'. And if you think JBoss causes this, it is in no way jsf or PrimeFaces  or SpringWebflow related. Create a new empty web app with no PrimeFaces and no SpringWebFlow just plain jsf. Does it happen then? Please narrow down the problem

Comment: It turns out Spring web flow's flow handler(org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter) is setting those values default to not cache.
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/WebContentGenerator.java#WebContentGenerator.0HEADER_EXPIRES

Comment: I spend days trying to overcome this not caching static resources in client browser and turns out the issue was in spring security config XML definition. There was cache-control enabled which is causing not to cache any of the static resources. I just deleted that tag from the definition and it is working like a charm. Thank you Kukeltje for directing me to right path.:

     <security:headers >
   <security:cache-control/>
   <security:content-type-options/>
   <security:frame-options/>
   <security:hsts/>
   <security:xss-protection/>
  </security:headers>